# Building a project on Eclipse didn't output any bin/*.jar file

Tags: android, eclipse

1. downloaded the following open source.
   https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel
2. Import /library to Eclipse as a Existing Android Code.
3. There's no error after building the project.

I would like to add the library to my developing app. So I guess I have to build it successfully with library.jar being output to /bin. Or is there other way to make dependency between them ?

Comment: `I have to build it successfully with library.jar being output to /bin.` **NO**. Libraries are included in the generated **apk** file.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `AndroidSlidingUpPanel` project as library project. After doing that, in eclipse, right click on your project in which you want to add the `AndroidSlidingUpPanel` project and go to properties. Then go to android section. In the bottom, click on add Library and select the project. You don't need to add jar manually, eclipse will do that for you.